# Ayuda por favor con cakephp 1.2, no lo doy solucionado

Tags: php, cakephp

a ver si alguien me puede ayudar, porque estoy un poco agobiado. Me han mandado trasladar una web en cakephp 1.2 a un servidor más moderno, está en internet information service 6.0 y la he montado en un apache en 1and1.
Funciona todo casi OK, pero la ruta de los posts:
cosnor2.idsoft.es/posts ( así tendría que ser, añade app/webroot y no encuentro la forma de solucionarlo ).

Incluso puedo pagar algo al que me ayude, que me escriba un privado a david@idsoft.es

gracias

fijaros que si cargais la web cosnor2.idsoft.es vais a noticias y carga pero en cuanto hacéis click en alguna ya añade /app/webroot y no se carga.

Y el error que me dá es:

> Error: The action webroot is not defined in controller AppController
>
> Error: Create AppController::webroot() in file:
>   app/controllers/app_controller.php.

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme, GRACIAS.

Y mi archivo routers.php en /app/config es:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 
'home'));


Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 
'display'));

//connect admin pages
Router::connect('/admin/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'admin' => true));

//alias for psot/news
Router::connect('/noticias', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index','Noticias'));

Router::connect('/admin/users/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/admin/users/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'admin_home', 'layout'=>'admin','admin'=>1 ,'prefix' => Configure::Read('Routing.admin')));
```

Comment: Sin embargo, si quitas el "/app/webroot" del enlace, funciona bien (ej http://cosnor2.idsoft.es/posts/ver_noticia/489 ). Los enlaces del menú también funcionan bien. Asumo que el problema pues está en la configuración de las noticias o en su plantilla.

Comment: Sí.  Eso ya lo vi pero no veo nada en las plantillas que añada eso.

Comment: A lo que iba es que ese código sería más útil que el de `routers.php`

Comment: Pues ya te digo, 'delCano', dime lo que quieras y te lo paso , seguro que es algo de la plantilla, puede ser

Comment: Perdona por pedirte ayuda, pero es que ando un poco agobiado ya que yo de cakephp ni idea y me encargaron el traslado y me está costando  mucho, es un servidor en internet information service 6.0 a un apache moderno. Veo que ya falta poco pero no lo doy conseguido, por eso el pedir la ayuda

Comment: No domino mucho CakePHP. Yo empezaría por un `grep` de la cadena `app/webroot' a ver si aparece en alguna parte del código; si no da resultado, un `grep` de `webroot` únicamente (estoy asumiendo que tienes acceso a una línea de comandos con el código). Con eso deberías poder encontrar si esa ruta ha sido codificada en algún sitio. Si no aparece, entonces debe estar en la configuración en la base de datos (y se complica un poco el asunto).

Comment: Gracias, ya hice eso también y nada, lo de la base de datos no.